# apply ecdf function to each column in dataframe and plot

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, plot

I want to apply my custom ecdf function on each column in a dataframe, then plot the ecdf based on the returned x,y values

the custom function:

```
def ecdf(df):
    n = len(df)
    x = np.sort(df)
    y = np.arange(1, n+1)/n
    return x, y
```

my attempt at a for loop:

```
for col in sj_interpol_data.columns:
   x_col, y_col = ecdf(col)
   ax = plt.figure()
   ax = plt.plot(x_col, y_col, marker='.', linestyle='none')
   ax = plt.margins=(0.02)
   plt.show()
```

Edited to include error:

```
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-d03c4fa0a973> in <module>()
      2 #design a for-loop which applies ecdf() on each column in df and plots them separately
      3 for col in sj_interpol_data.columns:
----> 4     x_col, y_col = ecdf(col)
      5     ax = plt.figure()
      6     ax = plt.plot(x_col, y_col, marker='.', linestyle='none')

<ipython-input-32-353fb281e367> in ecdf(df)
      4     n = len(df)
      5     #define x values - sorted values in array
----> 6     x = np.sort(df)
      7     #define y values - maps location of each datapoint WR to their percentiles
      8     y = np.arange(1, n+1)/n

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
    845     else:
    846         a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
--> 847     a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    848     return a
    849 

AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Any advice on how to write this function so it can be applied to all columns in a dataframe and automatically plot in a for loop?

Comment: We don't have any input or expected output here, how are we supposed to reproduce and fix the error?

Comment: In this line `x_col, y_col = ecdf(col)` you are passing the column *name*, not the df or the series. So in your `ecdf` function the `np.sort(df)` is trying to sort a string, which is where you are probably getting the error

Comment: apologies timgeb, the complete error is now displayed. Vivek you're right, the problem seems to be with np.sort. any advice on how to re-write the function so it applies to all columns in the df and also automatically plot in a loop? thanks very much guys

Answer (score 0):

You pass a column name into your ecdf function, yet you want to pass a dataframe into it, at least that's what your function definition indicates.

Comment: thanks Lennart the problem seems to be with np.sort (see comment above). any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I use df.sort_values() in the ecdf function, which uses pandas  to sort values instead of numpy

so the modified function is:

```
def ecdf(df):
    n = len(df)
    x = df.sort_values()
    y = np.arange(1, n+1)/n
    return x, y
```

after applyting the for loop (shown above), the output resulted in separate ecdf plots for each column in the dataframe